# How to disable a checkbox after executing onChange method?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input

I want to be able to disable a checkbox once I check on the checkbox and execute the onChange method.

I was able to find a way to do this, but once multiple items are checked only the recently checked checkbox is disabled.

The disable method is inside a component class before the render method

```
Disable = id => {
  document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;
  //another method to execute onchange
};
```

```html
<span>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    className="form-check-input"
    onChange={this.Disable}
    value=""
  />
</span>;
```

The checkbox is inside the render method.
One the user checks the checkbox the checkbox needs to check and disable it self

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some notice points:

- use **camelCase** for function name
- use props **value** to make the checkbox fully controlled
- use props **disabled** to disable input element
- set the related state inside the handler function
- no need for `document.getElementById` in your current situation
- handler event is not `id`, if you just need `id`, pass it as a param `this.handler(id)`

Demo:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState(true);
  const onChangeHandler = () => {
    setChecked(!checked);
    setStatus(false);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        value={checked}
        disabled={!status}
        onChange={onChangeHandler}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I want to be able to disable one checkbox when the onchange method is executed

Answer (score 1):

you should have to attach `id` on element .

```js
let Disable=(id)=>{
    if(id){
      document.getElementById(id).disabled = true
    }
}
```

```html
<span>
        <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" onChange="Disable(this.id)" id="one"  value=""/>
               <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" onChange="Disable(this.id)" id="two"  value=""/>
                      <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" onChange="Disable(this.id)"  id="three" value=""/>
                    </span>
```

Comment: Disable =(id) =>{
        if(id){
            id.disabled=true;
        }
        this.props.onClick();
    }

Answer (score 0):

passing the `event` in an **anonymous arrow function** and accepting it as an `argument` in the `eventHandler(component method)` and using the `event.target` there is the appropriate way of doing this in such situations that you need to access the caller.

```
class Stack extends Component {
  Disable = event => {
    event.target.disabled = true;
    //another method to execute onChange
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <span>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          className="form-check-input"
          onChange={event => this.Disable(event)}
          value=""
        />
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          className="form-check-input"
          onChange={event => this.Disable(event)}
          value=""
        />
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          className="form-check-input"
          onChange={event => this.Disable(event)}
          value=""
        />
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```